# Best Way to Count Occurences of Each Character in a Large Dataset

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of each character within a large dateset. For example, if the data was the numpy array ['A', 'AB', 'ABC'] then I would want {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 1} as the output. I currently have an implementation that looks like this:

```
char_count = {}
for c in string.printable:
    char_count[c] = np.char.count(data, c).sum()
```

The issue I am having is that this takes too long for my data. I have ~14,000,000 different strings that I would like to count and this implementation is not efficient for that amount of data. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way.

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter()
for thing in data:
    c.update(thing)
```

Same basic advantage - only iterates the data once.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This works a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

data = np.array(['A', 'AB', 'ABC'])

counts = defaultdict(int)
for e in data:
    for c in e:
        counts[c] += 1

print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 1})
```

Note that your code iterates `len(string.printable)` times over `data` in contrast my proposal iterates one time.

One alternative using a dictionary:

```
data = np.array(['A', 'AB', 'ABC'])

counts = dict()
for e in data:
    for c in e:
        counts[c] = counts.get(c, 0) + 1

print(counts)
```

Comment: Add collections.Counter and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is valid to no need to delete it :)